# Inserting file names in the database

Tags: php, xcode

Inserting file names in the database, with class MY_Upload

controller

```
$this->load->library('upload');

        //Configure upload.
        $this->upload->initialize(array(
            "upload_path"   => './public/uploads/album/',
            "allowed_types" => 'mp3',
            "max_size" => '2194304000',
            "overwrite" => 'FALSE'
        ));

        //Perform upload.
        if($this->upload->do_multi_upload("files")) {


            $arr = array(

                    'fx_title' => ?????,
                    'alb_id'  => $id,
                    'user_id'  => $user_id

            );

            $this->db->insert('nmp3_faixas', $arr);
        }
```

What value should I put in fx_title?

Comment: hola! what have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you write your question in english please?

Comment: Sorry for question in portugues @GerdK

Comment: I have tried
$fileName = $_POST['files']; @AmitThakur
not sucess!

Comment: Until now there is one translated version of stackoverflow and it is in Portugues... http://pt.stackoverflow.com/